# Simplifying a repetitive SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server

I've got a repetitive SQL query to populate a simple table based on subaccounts/years, from a list of amounts held by subaccounts/years, but there is not a one to one relationship. The output is for an SSRS report.

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Results](
      [SchemeDescription] [varchar](50) NULL,
      [SubAccountYear] [varchar](15) NULL,
      [RowNumber] [int] NULL,
      [2008] [money] NULL,
      [2009] [money] NULL,
      [2010] [money] NULL,
      [2011] [money] NULL,
      [2012] [money] NULL,
      [2013] [money] NULL,
      [2014] [money] NULL,
      [2015] [money] NULL,
      [2016] [money] NULL,
      [2017] [money] NULL,
      [2018] [money] NULL,
      [2019] [money] NULL,
      [2020] [money] NULL,
      [Processed] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
UPDATE res
      SET 
            [2008] = res.[2008] + isnull(x.[2008],0)
            ,[2009] = res.[2009] + isnull(x.[2009],0)
            ,[2010] = res.[2010] + isnull(x.[2010],0)
            ,[2011] = res.[2011] + isnull(x.[2011],0)
            ,[2012] = res.[2012] + isnull(x.[2012],0)
            ,[2013] = res.[2013] + isnull(x.[2013],0)
            ,[2014] = res.[2014] + isnull(x.[2014],0)
            ,[2015] = res.[2015] + isnull(x.[2015],0)
            ,[2016] = res.[2016] + isnull(x.[2016],0)
            ,[2017] = res.[2017] + isnull(x.[2017],0)
            ,[2018] = res.[2018] + isnull(x.[2018],0)
            ,[2019] = res.[2019] + isnull(x.[2019],0)
            ,[2020] = res.[2020] + isnull(x.[2020],0)
            ,processed = **1**
      FROM [Results] res
      INNER JOIN [Other_Income] as x
            ON x.SubAccountYear = Cast(Cast(res.SubAccount AS Int)as Varchar(10)) + '¬' 
+ Cast (YEAR(res.Inception_Date)+ **1** as varchar(4))
                AND x.Processed = 0
          WHERE res.RowNumber = 1
```

I have to repeat the query above 10 times to ensure that all of the subaccount years are apportioned to an appropriate subaccount, the figures surrounded by asterisks needs to enumerate from 1 to 10.

I'm sure there's another way, but it eludes.
Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you should wrap your update statement with a stored procedure that takes the processed value as a variable. something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateResults (
    @Processed int
)
AS
UPDATE res
  SET 
        [2008] = res.[2008] + isnull(x.[2008],0)
        ,[2009] = res.[2009] + isnull(x.[2009],0)
        ,[2010] = res.[2010] + isnull(x.[2010],0)
        ,[2011] = res.[2011] + isnull(x.[2011],0)
        ,[2012] = res.[2012] + isnull(x.[2012],0)
        ,[2013] = res.[2013] + isnull(x.[2013],0)
        ,[2014] = res.[2014] + isnull(x.[2014],0)
        ,[2015] = res.[2015] + isnull(x.[2015],0)
        ,[2016] = res.[2016] + isnull(x.[2016],0)
        ,[2017] = res.[2017] + isnull(x.[2017],0)
        ,[2018] = res.[2018] + isnull(x.[2018],0)
        ,[2019] = res.[2019] + isnull(x.[2019],0)
        ,[2020] = res.[2020] + isnull(x.[2020],0)
        ,processed = @Processed
  FROM [Results] res
  INNER JOIN [Other_Income] as x
        ON x.SubAccountYear = Cast(Cast(res.SubAccount AS Int)as Varchar(10)) + '¬' 
+ Cast (YEAR(res.Inception_Date)+ @Processed as varchar(4))
            AND x.Processed = 0
      WHERE res.RowNumber = 1
```

And then just execute it (perhaps in a while loop):

```
Declare @processed int = 1
While @processed < 11
begin
    exec UpdateResults @processed
    set @processed = @processed + 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I wondered whether i could use just SQL, rather than an SP or loop.